# Zoom from the pinch location using javascript in a canvas element

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, kineticjs, pinchzoom

Is there any way by which I can "Zoom In" from the point where I pinch and not from the center of the image in a Canvas element?

[This](http://2.s3.envato.com/files/78471334/fullscreen_image.html) is the example of what I need, but I need the same in canvas. When I "Zoom In", the zoom is made from the point from where I zoom and not the center of the image.

I am using `KineticJS` as `HTML5` Lib.

Comment: Do try what i have posted and get back here whether it worked out. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try using [zoomooz](http://jaukia.github.io/zoomooz/) plugin.

Its documentation contains a lotta functionalities.

This is the basic code of zooming in using the zoomooz plugin.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#element").click(function(evt) {
        $(this).zoomTo({targetsize:0.75, duration:600});
        evt.stopPropagation();
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks but i am looking for a way to do that on a canvas element.  Does this plugin support that?

Comment: You are using kinetic js right?
In that each of the images/elements can be fetched on click right?
So i assume you can,havent tried it out though.

The "this" in the code should point to the canvas element you wanna point to.